# Bourbaki-Witt in a textbook, other than in logic?

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, ho.history-overview, gm.general-mathematics

The Bourbaki-Witt theorem states that, in a chain-complete poset, the subset $X$ generated by an inflationary monotone function $s$ from the least element and joins of chains satisfies
$$ \forall x,y\in X.\quad s y\leq x \quad\lor\quad x\leq y. $$
From this one may deduce that $X$ is well ordered (in the original sense of Cantor) and has a top element, which is the unique fixed point of $s$ in $X$ and the least one in the larger poset.

Since we have a well-ordering, there is an induction principle: any property of the least element that is preserved by $s$ and joins of chains also holds for the least fixed point.

In fact Zermelo's second (1908) proof of the well ordering principle is exactly this. so the Bourbaki-Witt theorem should be attributed to Zermelo.

However, the Bourbaki and Witt papers appeared in 1949 and 1950.

Serge Lang's *Algebra* textbook contains it *in an appendix*.  Or rather, the $n$th printing does, for some $1< n\leq 9$.

**This fixed point theorem** (or its constructive replacement due to Dito Pataraia, 1997) **should be in the core of the pure mathematics curriculum**.

**Is there any textbook that proves it in Chapter 1 and then uses it throughout its development of its subject?**

I am interested in books in subjects such as some branch of algebra or topology, but not logic, set theory, lattice theory or order theory. Lattice theory considered as a form of algebra or topology would be reasonable.

I asked this question in connection with a seminar that I gave on 9 Dec 2022 about the history of order-theoretic fixed-point theorems, including my modification of Pataraia's constructive result. I did that work because I needed it for my paper on *Well founded coalgebras and recursion*. The slides for the seminar and the draft paper are on [my "ordinals" web page](http://www.paultaylor.eu/ordinals/) and include the full bibliographical details of the papers mentioned above.

The Wikipedia page supposedly about the Bourbaki-Witt theorem gives the correct citations but wrongly states that the proof was by transfinite recursion.

[This question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/441882) discusses the constructive result that should perform that same role as I am suggesting that the Bourbaki--Witt theorem ought to have done.

For further background please see [my webpage](http://paultaylor.eu/ordinals).  If you would like to take this up as a historical investigation, please contact me by email to get my trove of material.

My new [translations page](http://paultaylor.eu/trans/) includes the relevant one by Bourbaki and another by Walter Felscher comparing versions of the proof.

Comment: Can we give you lectures about the axiom of replacement though? (Joke explained [here](http://jdh.hamkins.org/transfinite-recursion-as-a-fundamental-principle-in-set-theory/).)

Comment: @Burak. Thanks, that looks interesting.  It seems to say that Replacement is closer than I thought to transfinite iteration of functors.  The latter is something that I can express as the existence of a left adjoint, ie in the mother tongue of category theory. The paper on *Well founded coalgebras* goes half way to doing that, but there is quite a lot more to write up before I can do all of it.

Comment: Why do you think this should be in the core of the undergraduate curriculum?  That seems like a pretty bold claim, and frankly I don’t understand your reasoning at all.

Comment: @AndyPutman: because of the ubiquity of recursive constructions. The Zermelo-Bourbaki-Witt argument was much simpler than the incoherent stuff about ordinals that students are taught.  The constructive Pataraia argument is much simpler still: see the other question and my webpage about that.

Comment: Ordinals are "incoherent"?  I'm not sure what you're getting at there.

Comment: @PaulTaylor Regarding this being in the core of the undergraduate curriculum: not all undergraduate curricula in pure mathematics include even a course on set theory. That's worth keeping in mind here.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda: "not all undergraduate curricula in pure mathematics include even a course on set theory".  Great! A lot do, though.  Anyway, what I advocate (elsewhere) is a massive tidying up of textbooks in algebra. What I'm *asking here* is whether anyone actually did this in the past.

Comment: @AndyPutman. "Ordinals are "incoherent".   Sorry you need to see my longer writings. I'm not going to explain that (repeatedly) in MO Comments. "Incoherent" was shorthand.

Comment: @PaulTaylor If it is not relevant to the question, why do you include a discussion (well, an assertion) about undergraduate curricula in your question?

Comment: @PaulTaylor: I think it's poor form to make a wild statement like that and then get annoyed and tell someone to read your papers (which I'm not going to do since I don't work in set theory) if they want to understand what you are saying.

Comment: @AndyPutman. I don't work in set theory either. The Question was whether there is any textbook in Algebra that is developed with the ZBW theorem in a fundamental role in the text.